# rails 4 has_one nested forms not building still

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, has-one

I have looked at all the posts about this fairly common problem on stackoverflow and elsewhere but I have not yet been able to find an answer. Essentially my nested form is not building, and is therefore not visible when I show the page.

Here is the relevant part of my user controller, `users_controller.rb`:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_user_account
  end
```

Here is the relevant section from my `user.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :user_account, :class_name => "UserAccount"
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_account
```

And my `user_account.rb` file:

```
    class UserAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

Here is my `_form.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %><br>
<%= f.text_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<% f.fields_for :user_account, @user.user_account do |user_account| %> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= user_account.label :email %>
    <%= user_account.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user_account.label :password %>
    <%= user_account.text_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user_account.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= user_account.text_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the first three show up as expected, but the three form fields for `user_account` do not show up. I've tried everything that I could find online, but I still haven't been able to work out what the problem is - help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have just missed the `=` sign in the `f.fields_for` line. Try like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_account, @user.user_account do |user_account| %>
```

The `@user.user_account` is not necessary either but does not harm.

Comment: oh gosh you're right, it works now! thank you so much!

Comment: You'll also not need to declare `class_name` for your `user_account` association